# How can I run tsserver as a background process on mobile (i.e. with JavaScriptCore but without node; and avoiding webview-based solutions)?

Tags: typescript, tsc, javascriptcore

I have made a simple JS text editor app for iOS; I'd like to use tsserver to get intellisense and transpilation. I can see how to run tsserver via node or via the browser (as part of TypeScript Playground – however, it comes along with the Monaco editor, and I want it headless, but I don't immediately see how to separate them).

One of the difficulties to consider is that it will presumably need file-system access to load any TypeScript libs (I will be loading it with many custom ones) – I'm not sure how to elegantly solve this with a purely JavaScriptCore solution.

Is there a way to set up just tsserver to run on mobile, ideally without getting a webview involved (as it's unnecessary overhead)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can see how to run tsserver via node or via the browser (as part of TypeScript Playground)

Micsonception here. tsserver *only* runs in node :  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Standalone-Server-(tsserver) `The TypeScript standalone server (aka tsserver) is a node executable`

## What runs on the playground?

The TypeScript *language* service https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API is what is run on the playground. It allows you to intercept calls like "does this file exist" or "please read this file" and redirect them to (*disk* for node, *server* for in browser) etc.

> Is there a way to set up just tsserver to run on mobile, ideally without getting a webview involved (as it's unnecessary overhead)?

So fundamentally no. tsserver is not for non node enviroments.

> however, it comes along with the Monaco editor, and I want it headless, but I don't immediately see how to separate them

If you want in browser IDE here is a nice free OSS one that *does use monaco* : https://github.com/agentcooper/typescript-play (but at least its open source through and through ). Monaco is not that bad. You have to start somewhere ❤

## More

In order to run TypeScript compiler over some set of files without running `tsc or tsserver` you have two options:

- Langauge Service / Language Service Host : Complex, but allows you to put an IDE front of your choice with live editing etc. *Some* docs here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API
- Just the Compiler API : Allows you to do a one time pass over a bunch of ts code to generate JavaScript / do error analysis. Example available here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

I think for your case (no IDE / live code editing etc) the compiler api would be sufficient.

Comment: Hi basarat, thanks immensely for clearing that up. I see now that actually what I am trying to run is the TS compiler (i.e., I want to make [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) API calls) on a mobile device (which also must host the service). The tricky part is that mobile devices don’t have node (they can only run JS via a browser or a runtime like JavaScriptCore). I’m wondering whether there is any way to set up tsc just via JavaScriptCore, rather than via a webview. And if it must be a webview, what are the minimal JS modules needed in the webpage?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong, I forgot about the *must work in JavaScript core*. `tsc` requires node as well. Correcting the answer.

Comment: @JamieBirch sounds like you want the compiler API. Answer updated. Thanks 